# Garbage values in array display c++

Tags: c++

When I tried to execute this code am getting the garbage values in the output.

```
int empid;
int unit500[] = {3,5,6,7,8,9};
int unit1000[] = {4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int unit924[] = {10, 9, 8, 5, 4, 3};
cout << "Enter emp id: ";
cin >> empid;
if(empid == 2)
{
    cout << empid << endl;
}
else if(empid == 500)
{
    for(int i=0; unit500[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        cout << unit500[i];
    }
}
else if(empid == 1000)
{
    for(int j=0; unit1000[j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
        cout << unit1000[j];
    }
}
else if(empid == 924)
{
    for(int k=0; unit924[k] != '\0'; k++)
    {
        cout << unit924[k];
    }
}
```

Output:

> Enter emp id: 500
>   35678950042012642293652942012642293584229365241989632147332096

Comment: how about looping from 0 to the array size  & not till ur element is different from '\0"?

Comment: None of those arrays contains a null character.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you looking for a `char` inside an array of `int` ? (Well, this is not an error, I just wanted to point out a consistency mistake here)

Actually, the character `'\0'` is promoted to the integer `0`. Since none of your arrays contain any `0`, you'll get an infinite loop for each of your `for` loops.

But it is probably not the behaviour you was expecting. It seems that you want to display the whole array.
Note that a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) array is not a *C String* so don't expect it to be *null-terminated* !
In this case, you just have to iterate until the size of the array is reached.

For example:

```
//...
int unit500[] = {3,5,6,7,8,9};

//...

// Get the size of unit500
const unsigned int unit500_size = sizeof(unit500) / sizeof(unit500[0]);

// Or (since C++17)
//const unsigned int unit500_size = std::size(unit500);

// Iterate until the last element of unit500
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < unit500_size; ++i)
{
    std::cout << unit500[i] << ", ";
}

//...
```

---

Of course, using `std::array` would be a better option. You could get the size in a significantly more readable way by simply calling the [`size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size) method.

Comment: Agreed that `std::array` is preferable (at least until the languages fixes the shortcomings of 'native' arrays). However, if one 'must' use a 'native' array, `std::size()` handles that since C++17.

Comment: I like your answer :) I just wanted to point out that \0 is not implicitily converted. \0 IS the null character:

http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1124.pdf

[page 61, example 12]

Comment: @underscore_d Oh right, I didn't think of it, I'll edit my answer accordingly. Thanks for the improvement :)

Comment: @crsn Thank you for the comment :) I know `'\0'` is the null character but we are considering here an array of `int` (and not `char`), so when the comparison occur, the `char` is promoted into an `int` (if I'm not mistaken). By the way, you linked a _C_ documentation, not a _C++_ one (since they are two completely different languages you can't apply it to both languages, the rules differ a lot).

Comment: I think this is still valid in C++
https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4820.pdf

page 452:

16.4.2.2.5.1 Byte strings [byte.strings]
1 A null-terminated byte string, or ntbs, is a character sequence whose highest-addressed element with defined
content has the value zero (the terminating null character); no other element in the sequence has the value
zero.

Comment: @crsn Yes, this is right, I just wanted to point out the semantic difference between `'\0'` as a `char` and `0` as an integer. Indeed the numeric values are exactly the same (`0`) but only the first one is called _null character_ (hence the semantic distinction). But I will correct my answer which is indeed incorrectly stated :)

Answer (score 0):

Your condition to end the loop is not adequate. Rather use a counter, loop until the counter is equal to the size of the array

```
for(int i=0; i<6/*size of array*/; i++){
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    int empid;
    std::vector<int> unit500 = { 3,5,6,7,8,9 };
    std::vector<int> unit1000 = { 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    std::vector<int> unit924 = { 10, 9, 8, 5, 4, 3 };
    std::cout << "Enter emp id: ";
    std::cin >> empid;
    if (empid == 2)
    {
        std::cout << empid << std::endl;
    }
    else if (empid == 500)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i != unit500.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << unit500[i];
        }
    }
    else if (empid == 1000)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j != unit1000.size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout << unit1000[j];
        }
    }
    else if (empid == 924)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k != unit924.size(); k++)
        {
            std::cout << unit924[k];
        }
    }
}
```

Garbage value because there is no '\0' character in integer arrays. By the way it's easier to work with vector rather than with arrays.